# JavaScript Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This wasn't the question I was going to ask but I have unexpectedly run aground with JavaScript arrays. I come from a PHP background and after looking at a few websites I am none the wiser.

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array.

```
var photos = new Array;
var a = 0;
$("#photos img").each(function(i) {
    photos[a]["url"] = this.src;
    photos[a]["caption"] = this.alt;
    photos[a]["background"] = this.css('background-color');
    a++;
});
```

Error message: photos[a] is undefined. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `this.css` won't work, you have to wrap `this` inside a jQuery object: `$(this).css`.

Comment: While the title indicates a duplicate, what the asker really wanted was an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

JavaScript does not have multidimensional arrays, but arrays of arrays, which can be used in a similar way.

You may want to try the following:

```
var photos = [];
var a = 0;
$("#photos img").each(function(i) {
    photos[a] = [];
    photos[a]["url"] = this.src;
    photos[a]["caption"] = this.alt;
    photos[a]["background"] = this.css('background-color');
    a++;
});
```

Note that you could have used `new Array()` instead of `[]`, but the latter is generally recommended. Also note that you were missing the parenthesis of `new Array()` in the first line.

---

**UPDATE:** Following from the comments below, in the above example there was no need to use arrays of arrays. An array of objects would have been more appropriate. The code is still valid because arrays are objects in this language, but the following would have been better:

```
photos[a] = {};
photos[a]["url"] = this.src;
photos[a]["caption"] = this.alt;
photos[a]["background"] = this.css('background-color');
```

Comment: An Array holds numeric keys, not strings.

Comment: @Alsciende: That code is valid. An array is an object in JavaScript, and objects and hashtables are the same thing in this language. Therefore `photos[0]["url"]` is assigning a `url` property to `photos[0]`.

Comment: It's valid, but it's not proper. There's no point using an Array in that case, it's just confusing for novice people.

Comment: It's better to use `photos[a] = {};`

Comment: @Alsciende: You have a point. Let me clarify the answer.

Comment: @Alsciende: +1ed your answer. Your implementation is definitely better. Mine was just an attempt to address the OP's misunderstanding of arrays and multidimensional arrays.

Comment: you're right the correct way is `photos[a]={};` and not `[]`, because `var x=[]; x['foo']='bar'; alert(x.length) //0` you can see you're not populating the array, but acctually the object properties.

Answer (score 16):

You're trying to assign something to `photos[a]["url"]`, `photos[a]["caption"]`, etc., but `photos[a]` doesn't exist yet. `photos` is an empty Array at first, so you have to set `photos[a]` to something first. Since you want to use string keys (`"url"`, `"caption"`, etc), this something should be a plain object (the javascript equivalent to php associave arrays) (or a Hash if your code base allows it). Then you can use a literal object construct to simplify your function, and `Array#push` to get rid of the unnecessary `a`:

```
var photos = [];
$("#photos img").each(function(img) {
    photos.push({
      url: img.src,
      caption: img.alt,
      background: img.style.backgroundColor
    });
});
```

Also, make sure that `this` is actually your `img` element. Some `each` implementations will set `this` to the global object in your case.

edit: ok, it looks like `jQuery.each` automatically sets `this` to the iterated element, but doesn't wrap it in jQuery-goodness, so you have to either wrap `this` in `$()` or use plain DOM (I used the latter in my example).

edit2: anyway, using `this` is kind of strange since the callback function passed to `each` receives an argument. Might as well use this argument (renamed).

Comment: The only problem with `this` is that it doesn't have a `css` method. It must first be wrapped inside a jQuery object.

Comment: I don't much about jQuery. I'll use your advice.

Answer (score 5):

```
var photos = [];
var imgs = document.getElementById("photos").getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    photos.push({
        src:imgs[i].src,
        alt:imgs[i].alt,
        background:imgs[i].style.backgroundColor
    });
}
```

That should give you something that is roughly equivalent to this in PHP (I made up pretend data):

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        "src" => "logo.png",
        "alt" => "My Logo!",
        "background" => "#ffffff"
    )
)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for coding in plain js when possible

Answer (score 2):

When I read this thread I was trying to get an understanding of multidimensional associative arrays. It wasn't clear so I kept researching, this is what I came up with:

```
var images = new Array;
images['logo'] = { 'src': 'http://example.com/image1.png', 'caption': 'this is the logo', 'background':  '#000'};
images['background'] = { 'src': 'http://example.com/image2.png', 'caption': 'this is the background', 'background':  '#FFF'};
alert(images['logo']['src']); /* output: http://example.com/image1.png */
alert(images['background']['caption']); /* output: this is the background */
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

multi-dimensional arrays are in these structure:

```
var photos = new Array();
photos[0] = new Array();
```

use it as :

```
photos[0][0] = this.src;
```

more on JS array [here](http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=defining+js+arrays&parent=js+arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Crockford, of [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), would have you create it this way ("*Use the array literal notation []*"):

```
var photos = [];
```

Now remember that you want to create multi-dimensional arrays, which means an array inside an array. This means you need to create the inner-arrays:

```
$("#photos img").each(function(i) {
  photos[a] = []
  //continue
```