# Is it possible to define and initialize multidimensional arrays in JavaScript in one line of code?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is too basic, but I am struggling at defining 4-dimensional array (of size 6x6x6x6) in JavaScript and initializing it to all 1's. What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Multidimensional Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808926/javascript-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: Javascript does not have multidimensional arrays but rather arrays of arrays.

Comment: @Frankie multidimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by of size 6,6,6,6?

Comment: @ddlshack: 4-dimensional array with size of each dimension = 6, obviously. `[[[[1]]]]` <--- this is example of `1x1x1x1`

Comment: @ddlshack well not really; a multi-dimensional array in a language like C or FORTRAN has fixed values for each dimension and is stored in a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: On a side-note, how would you generalise the creation of an n-dimensional AxBxCxDx... matrix?

Comment: @ddlshack, there is a slight difference... and John has put it very elegantly here http://stackoverflow.com/a/597790/67945

Answer (score 3):

You can use the literal syntax, but it would be very big and cumbersome. You may want to try something like this:

```
var x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    x = [x, x, x, x, x, x];
}
```

I found a slightly simpler solution:

```
var x = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    x = [x, x, x, x, x, x];
}
```

Comment: thanks! btw, this question wasn't a challenge, i needed this for a combinatorics-related problem and you saved my day :) funny that defining an array could be so unintuitive...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there should be easier way, but this will do it.

```
var array = [];

for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<6; j++) {
        for(var k=0; k<6; k++) {
            for(var l=0; l<6; l++) {
                array[i][j][k][l]=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To generate an n-dimensional AxBxCxDx... array (untested):

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(elem, n) {
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++, this.push(elem));
}

function generateArray() {
    var dimensions = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    var x = 1;
    for (var i = dimensions.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        x = [].fill(x, dimensions[i]);
    }
    return x;
}
```

to generate a 2x3x4x5 matrix:

```
generateArray(2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: mikez302's solution is better. However, this will allow you to create an AxBxCxD matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented ddlshack's generalized method, but ran into an issue due to the fact that arrays are "pass by reference" in JavaScript.  This resulted in each dimension of the array holding multiple references to the same array rather than copies of it.  To correct the issue, I implemented the solution as follows (the only other difference being that I used a second function rather than modify Array's prototype).

```
var fillArray = function(val, dim) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === "[object Array]") {
            val = val.slice(0);
        }

        a.push(val);
    }

        return a;
};

var generateArray = function() {
    var dimensions = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        val = 0;

    for (var i = (dimensions.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        val = fillArray(val, dimensions[i]);
    }

    return val;
};
```