# accessing multidimensional array string

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access the first and second element of a multidimensional string array.
Unsuccessfully.

Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6868b2413a7220bf130a

If i replace the variables like this example:

```
var question = location[math[0]]

var question = location[math]
```

It works as intended but displays the answers.

What kind of quiz would that be?!

Comment: Should be `location[math][0]` and `location[math][1]` respectively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, but that would display the answer. location[[0  1]]; Where 0 is the question and 1 is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try ...

```
var question = location[math][0];
```

... and ...

```
var question = location[math][1];
```

`math` per the referenced code is simply a number that is from zero to the length of location; this is the proper notation to get the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

First thought is that this isn't the best way of implementing a quiz, since the user can go right ahead and peak at the answers by inspecting the script?

That said, JS doesn't actually have 2D arrays, instead arrays of arrays!  See here: [JavaScript Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808926/javascript-multidimensional-arrays) so you will need to change it to something like:

```
answer = location[math][1];
```

You should then find it works!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, had to use an object, here is the code.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/319b88cd11a9a3958b6f

The quiz is for myself.
Thank you for your time