# jQuery TypeError: array index is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have some `divs` and need to store data of each `div` in a array. So i used a two dimensional array to store these data in following way.

```
this.saveBoardAndNotes = function (board_id, board_name) {
        var noteList = new Array(new Array());
        var self = this;
        var count = 0;

        $(".optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note").each(function(){
            // Replace plain urls with links and improve html
            var note = $(this);
            var content = note.find(".textarea").html();
            var properties = JSON.stringify(self.getProperties(note));
            var noteID = note.attr("id");

            noteList[count]['content'] = content;
            noteList[count]['properties'] = properties;
            noteList[count]['noteID'] = noteID;

            count++;
        });
```

But i get following error in firebug when i try to store more than one div in array

`TypeError: noteList[count] is undefined`

How can i solve the problem. By the way, is there any optimized way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen creating a two-dimensional array in JavaScript this way.

Comment: I used following reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808926/javascript-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: You've missed the line `photos[a] = [];` ; ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you create "two-dimentional" array is not optimal for this task. You would better use an array of objects which you can create like this:

```
var noteList = [];
var self = this;
var count = 0;

$(".optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note").each(function () {
    // Replace plain urls with links and improve html
    var note = $(this);
    var content = note.find(".textarea").html();
    var properties = JSON.stringify(self.getProperties(note));
    var noteID = note.attr("id");

    noteList[count] = {};
    noteList[count]['content'] = content;
    noteList[count]['properties'] = properties;
    noteList[count]['noteID'] = noteID;

    count++;
});
```

However what you really need is to use [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var self = this;

var noteList = $(".optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note").map(function () {
    // Replace plain urls with links and improve html
    var note = $(this);
    var content = note.find(".textarea").html();
    var properties = JSON.stringify(self.getProperties(note));
    var noteID = note.attr("id");

    return {
        content: content,
        properties: properties,
        noteID: noteID
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
var noteList = new Array(new Array());
```

you have an array of arrays. This is fine, but you cannot set property values as if you were using an object. Instead of

```
noteList[count]['content'] = content;
```

you would have to do

`noteList[count].push(content)`;

If you wish to push objects, you can do

```
var myObj = {
'content' : content,
'properties' : properties,
'noteID' : noteID
};
noteList[count].push(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.saveBoardAndNotes = function (board_id, board_name) {
        var noteList = [];
        var self = this;
        var count = 0;

        $(".optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note").each(function(){
            // Replace plain urls with links and improve html
            var note = $(this);
            var content = note.find(".textarea").html();
            var properties = JSON.stringify(self.getProperties(note));
            var noteID = note.attr("id");

            noteList[count] = {};
            noteList[count]['content'] = content;
            noteList[count]['properties'] = properties;
            noteList[count]['noteID'] = noteID;

            count++;
        });
```